# create-react-library not working with styled components

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `create-react-library` to build my component library, and I've attempted to use Styled Components, but I keep getting a React hooks error.

Here's my code: https://github.com/emmabostian/component-library

And here's the error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I am not using React hooks anywhere, my React and React DOM versions match and I do not have multiple versions of React.

Answer (score 1):

Check your package.json file you appear to have dependencies react / react-dom version 16 but peer dependencies for versions 15 . I think this is the cause of your problem , remove the peer dependencies. Also you don't need to write your components as class based if all you are doing is rendering use a functional component approach instead.

Comment: I removed the peer dependencies but it didn't fix the issue. And I know I can write them as SFC but this was the boilerplate from the library and I didn't refactor it.

Comment: I'll clone your lib and run it. and get back to you.

Comment: You seem to have just updated your peer dependency versions,  why are peer dependencies requeired / Can't you just remove these ?

Comment: From other issues like this , they suggest remove your package.json lock file and node modules and re run install.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get your app running please.

Comment: So I just removed the peer dependencies, deleted yarn lock and tried a fresh install but got a weird error: "Error: 'useContext' is not exported by node_modules/react/index.js"

Comment: You should run `yarn start` in the root and in a second window cd into `example` and run `yarn start`. This will open the browser window with the example and this is what breaks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206522/discussion-between-emmawedekind-and-dorriz).

Comment: the error of useContext happened to me as well. it seems like some rollup thing and common js module of react

Comment: I am facing the same issue that you mentioned here after setting up your app. It seems the error is somewhere here 
 return useStyledComponentImpl(WrappedStyledComponent, props, ref);

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies in the included example project are very outdated.

Instead I set up a new separate example project, which perfectly renders your button:

```
npx create-react-app component-library-example
cd component-library-example
npm install --save emmas-super-cool-component-library
npm start
```

App.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { PrimaryButton } from "emmas-super-cool-component-library";

const App = () => (
  <PrimaryButton
    onClickHandler={() => {
      alert("clicked");
    }}
  >
    text
  </PrimaryButton>
);

export default App;
```

Result:

[image: App]

Comment: I think the published version and the one having issues is different. There is no PrimaryButton exported from the version she is facing an error

Comment: I haven't published the current version to npm because it's so broken. The published version is a plain React button so yeah it definitely renders :/

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used create-react-library, and had encountered the same issue. The error message exactly makes sense in this case. The issue will not happen when you actually publish the package and consume it at a consumer application. This means, the problem is with your `example` folder. If you look at `package.json`, that's inside `example` folder, you can see there are library references for react, react-scripts, react-dom etc. Referring those with file protocol like below will solve your problem.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "library-name": "file:..",
    "react": "file:../node_modules/react",
    "react-dom": "file:../node_modules/react-dom",
    "react-scripts": "file:../node_modules/react-scripts"
    "node-sass": "file:../node_modules/node-sass"
  },
```

Clear your `node_modules` as well as `package-lock.json` before trying this.